# Java reflection of Scala 2.11 case class returns non-declared fields?

Tags: java, scala, reflection, case-class

Currently trying to make a Java driver compatible with Scala case classes. The problem is that reflection is failing pretty bad.

Basically, a lot of unwanted fields are coming through and fields like `ANNOTATION` and `getModifiers` are being inserted. However, when I inspect using the debugger, the `pojo` in the code below is indeed `models.User`. However, calling `getClass()` on `pojo` yields `java.lang.Class`.

I've also tried making each field in the case class `val` and then calling `.getDeclaredFields()` on the class, but it has the same effect.

Any idea why this is happening? Here's the Java code:

```
private static Map<String, Object> toMap(Object pojo) {
    try {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        Class pojoClass = pojo.getClass();

        if (!Modifier.isPublic(pojoClass.getModifiers())) {
            throw new IllegalAccessException(String.format("%s's class should be public", pojo));
        }

        for (Field field : pojoClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
            System.out.println(field.toString());
        }

        for (Field field : pojoClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);

            if (field.getDeclaringClass() == pojoClass) {
                Object value = field.get(pojo);

                if (value instanceof Integer) {
                    throw new IllegalAccessException(String.format(
                            "Make %s of %s Long instead of Integer", field.getName(), pojo));
                }

                map.put(field.getName(), value);
            }
        }

        return map;
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new ReqlDriverError("Can't convert %s to a ReqlAst: %s", pojo, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here's what my Scala case class looks like:

```
case class User(
  userId: String,
  loginInfo: LoginInfo,
  firstName: Option[String],
  lastName: Option[String],
  fullName: Option[String],
  email: Option[String],
  avatarURL: Option[String]) extends Identity
```

And if I iterate through `getDeclaredFields()` I get the following:

```
ANNOTATION
ENUM
SYNTHETIC
cachedConstructor
newInstanceCallerCache
name
allPermDomain
useCaches
reflectionData
classRedefinedCount
genericInfo
serialVersionUID
serialPersistentFields
reflectionFactory
initted
enumConstants
enumConstantDirectory
annotationData
annotationType
classValueMap
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are listing fields of `Class`:

```
scala> classOf[Class[_]].getDeclaredFields
res4: Array[java.lang.reflect.Field] = Array(private static final int java.lang.Class.ANNOTATION, private static final int java.lang.Class.ENUM, private static final int java.lang.Class.SYNTHETIC, private transient volatile java.lang.reflect.Constructor java.lang.Class.cachedConstructor, private transient volatile java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.newInstanceCallerCache, private transient java.lang.String java.lang.Class.name, private static java.security.ProtectionDomain java.lang.Class.allPermDomain, private static boolean java.lang.Class.useCaches, private transient volatile java.lang.ref.SoftReference java.lang.Class.reflectionData, private transient volatile int java.lang.Class.classRedefinedCount, private transient volatile sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository java.lang.C...
```

I don't know what `Identity` is.

Scala:

```
package ccreflect

case class User(
  userId: String,
  loginInfo: String,
  firstName: Option[String],
  lastName: Option[String],
  fullName: Option[String],
  email: Option[String],
  avatarURL: Option[String])

object Test extends App {
  Console println runtime.ScalaRunTime.stringOf(
    Util.toMap(User("Bob", "xxx", None, None, None, None, None))
  )
}
```

Java:

```
package ccreflect;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.lang.reflect.*;


public class Util {

public static Map<String, Object> toMap(Object pojo) {
    try {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        Class pojoClass = pojo.getClass();

        if (!Modifier.isPublic(pojoClass.getModifiers())) {
            throw new IllegalAccessException(String.format("%s's class should be public", pojo));
        }

        for (Field field : pojoClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
            System.out.println(field.toString());
        }

        for (Field field : pojoClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);

            if (field.getDeclaringClass() == pojoClass) {
                Object value = field.get(pojo);

                if (value instanceof Integer) {
                    throw new IllegalAccessException(String.format(
                            "Make %s of %s Long instead of Integer", field.getName(), pojo));
                }

                map.put(field.getName(), value);
            }
        }

        return map;
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Can't convert %s to a ReqlAst: %s", pojo, e.getMessage()));
    }
}
}
```

with result

```
$ scala ccreflect.Test
private final java.lang.String ccreflect.User.userId
private final java.lang.String ccreflect.User.loginInfo
private final scala.Option ccreflect.User.firstName
private final scala.Option ccreflect.User.lastName
private final scala.Option ccreflect.User.fullName
private final scala.Option ccreflect.User.email
private final scala.Option ccreflect.User.avatarURL
{firstName=None, lastName=None, avatarURL=None, loginInfo=xxx, fullName=None, userId=Bob, email=None}
```

Comment: Whoops sorry that was some debugging code I accidentally pasted in. Totally my fault I'm editing it now. It actually doesn't change the end result.

Comment: Sorry, I meant you're reflecting a Class; these are fields of Class, not Foo.class. Are you calling `toMap(foo.getClass)`?

Comment: Ah thanks for the response. No that's not how it's being called. It's actually a file I'm debugging in the RethinkDB driver located here: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/blob/josh/java-driver/drivers/java/src/main/java/com/rethinkdb/ast/Util.java#L120  It looks like `case class` compatibility just isn't going to work (although I thought it was a solved problem?) You'll see that the POJO is actually passed before `.getClass` is called on it.

Comment: Negative the link I included in my previous comment is the new Java driver that's about to be released for RethinkDB.